# Make a TreeView with Sqlite and PyQT5

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I'm trying to add items inside the QTreeWidget when I add items to my SQLite Database. My Problem is I want to add items as a child to the given other items. Let me show you it inside code. This is my Gui example:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(213, 327)
        Form.setWindowTitle("Form")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(Form)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 211, 311))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "Categories")
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.printtree()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def printtree(self):
        rn = readsql_Names()
        self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        treeItem = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([rn])
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(treeItem)


        def displaytree():
            conn = connect_DB() # Connection to the Database 
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            table = cursor.execute(f"SELECT NAME FROM Test")
            for item in table.fetchall():
                name = str(item[0])
                branch_list = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([name])
                treeItem.addChild(branch_list)
                # I guess here should be a if statement.
                branch_list.addChild(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["name"]))
        displaytree()
```

And this is how my SQLite looks like:

```
def create_testsql(Tree_Table="Test"):
    conn = connect_DB()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {Tree_Table} \
            (ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, \
            PARENTID INTEGER, \
            NAME TEXT NOT NULL)")
        conn.commit()
    except:
        print("Failure! Creating the TEST Table has failed.")
```

So I want to check if a Parent Id = ID then it should be showed as a child in the QTreeView. Somehow I have to change printtree function but I don't know how.

That how it should look like when I add item4 when ParentID = ID of item2.

My Tree View Example

[image]

Comment: Since sql tables are not sorted, you cannot do this in a single for loop, as you might find child items with parents that have not been created yet. You have to cycle through the contents, if you find parent items add them to the tree, if they're child add them to a temporary list (with a reference to the parent index) and then in another cycle go through those child items and add them to the parents. That said, you should not modify pyuic created files, read the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @musicamante said it was not possible in a single for loop. So I created a General table where the Item_ID from the Item_Table and the Tree_ID from the Tree_Table was referenced as a Foreign Keys and got an ID which is Unique. Then I run a for loop inside the General table and a if else statement to sort them like:

```
if item_id == "null":
  treeWidget.addTopLevelItem
else:
  addChild
```